# how to count duplicated rows in mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

hello i want to count how many customers who bought from my website more than one time 
but the problem is i want to count how many customers in this month who bought something this month or before 
this is my tables

orders

```
---------------------------------------
|id   | phone  |  name     |    date    |
---------------------------------------
| 1   | 000001 |   name 1  | this month |
| 2   | 000002 |   name 2  | last month |
| 3   | 000001 |   name 1  | last month |
| 4   | 000003 |   name 3  | this month |
```

name is not important here so my query is

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT (o.phone)) AS total,
    COUNT(IF((SELECT 
                COUNT(o2.id)
            FROM
                orders o2
            WHERE
                o2.phone = o.phone) > 1,
        1,
        NULL)) AS returned
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    date = 'this month'
```

this gives me in `returned` 2 i know it's looping on everything that's why it count the (name 2) two times.

i need a solution to count it just one time i searched a lot and i didn't find anything

and thanks for your help .

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you identify a customer by their phone. You want to count the number of different customers in this month and also count how many of these are returning customers.

One way is conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as total, sum(is_returning) as returning
from
(
  select phone, max(date = 'last month') as is_returning
  from orders
  group by phone
  having max(date = 'this month')
) customers;
```

(`MAX` on a boolean expression is an OR aggregation in MySQL, i.e. if at least one value is true, the result is true. `SUM` on a boolean expression in MySQL counts the true expressions.)

Comment: thank you it's working i just had to make a small change but the idea is what i am looking for 
i changed ```select phone, max(date = 'last month') as is_returning``` in subquery to 
```select phone, if(count(id) > 1, 1, 0) AS is_returning```